# options attribute of select element does not work in vue.js 2.0

Tags: javascript, vue.js, html-select

I read in [Vue.js 0.12 Guide](https://012.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html#Dynamic_Select_Options) that you can dynamically produce `option` tags inside a `select` tag with `options` attribute like below:

```
<select v-model="selected" options="myOptions"></select>
```

But it does not work in Vue.js 2.0 and I have to use `v-for` directive.
Is this feature removed in version 2.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been deprecated since the 1.0 version, as mentioned in [an old issue (#1229) on the official repo](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/1229).

> ## Problem
>
> The options param has been a common gotcha when dealing with `v-model`
>   on `<select>` elements. It often requires additional formatting of the
>   source data with a custom filter, and has limited capabilities in
>   customizing the rendered options.
>
> ## Proposal
>
> The reason options existed was due to some internal implementation
>   issues - there is really no reason for it to be that way from the UX
>   perspective. Therefore in 1.0, with some internal refactoring, we will
>   deprecate the `options` param - instead, just use a normal `v-for`:
>
> ```
> <select v-model="selected">
>   <option v-for="option in list">{{option}}</option>
> </select>
> ```
>
> If you have an Array of objects, you can also bind the underlying
>   `v-model` value directly to the object by using `v-bind:value` on the
>   options:
>
> ```
> <select v-model="selected">
>   <option v-for="obj in objList" v-bind:value="obj">{{obj.description}}</option>
> </select>
> ```